# Align first column entry corresponding to multiple row entry in second column

Tags: tables, align

I am trying to align column entry in 1st column and 2nd row with corresponding second column entry.

I am using following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}l l l}
a \ & & 1, 2, 3 \\
b & & \begin{tabular}[l]{@{}l@{}} 1\\ 2\\ 3\end{tabular} \\
c & & 1, 2, 3 \\

\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

What parameter do I need to change so that b is not in center of `1` `2` `3` but it should be at top next to value `1`. 
Desired Output:

```
a       1,2,3
b       1
        2
        3
c       1,2,3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}l l l}
a & & 1, 2, 3 \\
b & & 1, 2, 3 \\
c & & 1, 2, 3 \\

\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

### EDIT

following OP edit

Or this

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}l l l}
a & & 1, 2, 3 \\
b & & 1        \\
  & & 2         \\
  & & 3         \\
c & & 1, 2, 3 \\

\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not what I want kindly look at desired output as stated in question.

Answer (score 1):

THree other solutions; you can do that either with`makecell` or with `stackengine` (`\Shortunderstack`  or `\Longunderstack`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}l l l}
a \ & & 1, 2, 3 \\
b & & \makecell[tl]{1\\ 2\\ 3} \\
c & & 1, 2, 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\qquad
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}l l l}
a \ & & 1, 2, 3 \\
b & & \Longunderstack[l]{1\\2\\ 3} \\
\noalign{\vskip 0.6ex}
c & & 1, 2, 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\qquad
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}l l l}
a \ & & 1, 2, 3 \\
b & & \Shortunderstack[l]{1\\2\\ 3\\} \\
c & & 1, 2, 3 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]